# Make user choose which 2-Factors authentification method to use keycloak

Tags: java, freemarker, keycloak

I'm using an application based on keycloak which provides a two factors authentifications with SMS, I have added Mail also to this app but I want the user to choose which methode he wants to use to get the code (Mail or SMS).

Something like that : 
[Link : window to choose authentification flow method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMvnn.png)

Any Idea please ?

Thank you !

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific and also show us some code.

Comment: Which part of the code do you want to see ?